# Angular 7 lifecycle when the whole page is loaded and data bound and renderred

Tags: angular

I am trying to track any data change in the page.

I tried to manage it myself:
   1. have a dataChanged variable
   2. set it to false after the page is fully loaded
   3. set it to true when any data field changed
   4. set it to false when data saved on current page

What life cycle for step 2? I tried OnInit, OnViewInit, AfterViewInit, AfterContentChecked, neither works for me.

Does Angular provide any API for detecting data change on page? Any example for this?

Answer (score 0):

**MutationObserver**

> The MutationObserver interface provides the ability to watch for
>   changes being made to the DOM tree. It is designed as a replacement
>   for the older Mutation Events feature which was part of the DOM3
>   Events specification

How to implement in angular check this:https://nitayneeman.com/posts/listening-to-dom-changes-using-mutationobserver-in-angular/